# How to specify an elastic beanstalk deployment using spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

Please forgive me, I just started using spinnaker.
I have a war file that is currently deployed on tomcat using elastic beanstalk.
Is there a way to specify a deployment using a war file to elastic beanstalk using tomcat with spinnaker?

Comment: unfortunately elastic beanstalk is not supported in spinnaker. You should be able to see the image in the clusters view and use EC2 to deploy it

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to Beanstalk by using the Jenkins stage and then deploy a Cloudformation template with the CF stage.

Basically you just have to set up the [AWS Provider](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ec2/) in halyard and then enable the [Cloud Formation Stage](https://community.spinnaker.io/t/cloudformation-stage-how-to-enable-and-configure/1478/5)